# Given a connected and ready DiscordSocketClient and a Discord Channel Id, How does one send a message to that channel?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to set up automated messages.

When I am setting up my `client` I use:

```
client.Ready += OnClientReady;
```

From there I start my `Scheduler` class:

```
private Task OnClientReady()
{
    var scheduler = new Scheduler(client);
    scheduler.Start();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Which looks like this:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private static Timer _timer;

    public void Start(object state = null)
    {
        Sender.Send(_client);

        _timer = new Timer(Start, null, (int)Duration.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds, 0);
    }

    public Scheduler(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

When the timer ticks, it calls out and passes the `client` to the `Sender` class below:

```
public static class Sender
{
    public static void Send(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        var currentLocalDateTime = SystemClock.Instance.InTzdbSystemDefaultZone().GetCurrentLocalDateTime();

        var elapsedRotations = new List<Rotations>();
        using (var db = new GOPContext())
        {
            elapsedRotations = db.Rotations
                                 .Include(r => r.RotationUsers)
                                 .Where(r => r.LastNotification == null ||
                                             Period.Between(r.LastNotification.Value.ToLocalDateTime(),
                                                            currentLocalDateTime).Hours >= 23)
                                 .ToList();
        }

        foreach (var rotation in elapsedRotations)
        {
            var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(rotation.Timezone);
            var zonedDateTime = SystemClock.Instance.InZone(zone).GetCurrentZonedDateTime();
            if (zonedDateTime.Hour != 17)
                continue;

            //I need to send a message to the channel here.
            //I have access to the connected / ready client, 
            //and the channel Id which is "rotation.ChannelId"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried getting the channel like this:

```
var channel = client.GetChannel((ulong) rotation.ChannelId);
```

which gives me a `SocketChannel` and also like this:

```
var channel = client.Guilds
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Channels)
                    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == rotation.ChannelId);
```

which gives me a `SocketGuildChannel`.  Neither of these give me an option to send a message directly to the channel.  I have tried researching how to do this, but have not found anything...  The documentation does not seem to have any examples of this...

It seems like a simple thing to do, but I'm at my wits end on it.  Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both `SocketGuildChannel` and `SocketChannel` could be either a voice or a text channel.

Instead you want the `ISocketMessageChannel`, `IMessageChannel` or `SocketTextChannel`

To get this you could simply cast the `SocketChannel` you are getting

```
var channel = client.GetChannel((ulong) rotation.ChannelId);
var textChannel = channel as IMessageChannel;
if(textChannel == null)
    // this was not a text channel, but a voice channel
else
    textChannel.SendMessageAsync("This is a text channel");
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!  I have never used the voice channels in discord, so it never even crossed my mind.  You can also get a list of TextChannels from a given `SocketGuild`.